# Hiding base class constructor parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to understand how to hide a base constructor parameter in a subclass in kotlin.  How do you put a facade over a base constructor?  This doesn't work:

```
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response

class MyCustomRequest(url: String)
      : Request<String>(Request.Method.POST, url, hiddenListener) {
    private fun hiddenListener() = Response.ErrorListener {
        /* super secret listener */
    }
    ...
}
```

I think I understand the problem:

> During construction of a new instance of a derived class, the base
>   class initialization is done as the first step (preceded only by
>   evaluation of the arguments for the base class constructor) and thus
>   happens before the initialization logic of the derived class is run.

I'm trying to solve this problem for Volley, where I need my custom request to be be a Request so that it can be passed into a RequestQueue.  It would be easier of RequestQueue took in some kind of interface but since it doesn't I have to subclass.  There are other ways I can hide these complexities from the caller, but this limitation has come up for me other times in Kotlin and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with volley but I tried to come up with an example that should give you some insight how to solve your problem. What you can do is use a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

```
interface MyListener {
    fun handleEvent()
}

open class Base<T>(anything: Any, val listener: MyListener) { // this would be your Request class
    fun onSomeEvent() {
        listener.handleEvent()
    }
}

class Derived(anything: Any) : Base<Any>(anything, hiddenListener) { // this would be your MyCustomRequest class
    private companion object {
        private val hiddenListener  = object : MyListener {
            override fun handleEvent() {
                // do secret stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if you apply this to your problem, the result should look something like this:

```
class MyCustomRequest(url: String)
    : Request<String>(Request.Method.POST, url, hiddenListener) {
    private companion object {
        private val hiddenListener = Response.ErrorListener {
            /* super secret listener */
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

A different way would be to use a [decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator), create your Request withing that decorator and just delegate the calls to it:

```
class Decorator(anything: Any) {
    private var inner: Base<Any>
    private val hiddenListener: MyListener =  object : MyListener {
        override fun handleEvent() {  }
    }
    init {
        inner = Base(anything, hiddenListener)
    }
}
```

And once again for your example that would look like this:

```
class MyCustomRequest(url: String) {
    private var inner: Request<String>
    private val hiddenListener = Response.ErrorListener {
        /* super secret listener */
    }
    init {
        inner = Request<String>(Request.Method.POST, url, hiddenListener)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that companion objects can't reference things in its containing class, because they're more or less like statics would be in Java.  So I could do that, but part of the reason I'm trying to do this is that the hidden listener can do something with the result, by calling methods of MyCustomRequest or otherwise changing its state.  So I think I'm boxed in ?

Comment: OK i see your problem. You could maybe solve this using a decorator instead of inheritance. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: OH yeah, that kind of works ... then I can provide an accessor for the underlying object, and use that for calls that require I pass in a Volley Request<T> (and not actually have to extend Request<T> myself).  Thanks for the suggestion.